# transform tf.dataset to 4D tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I just study TensorFlow and faced with this problem - when I feed tf.dataset to model.fit I receive an error

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28, 1)

I understand that it should be 4D tensor -  (number of items, rows, columns, channels) when parameter data_format is "channels_last". but I have tf.Ddataset only which I received after loading dataset. Thus, my question is how to transform tf.Dataset to 4D tensor in order to be able to feed it to the model? can somebody show me code or point to a suitable article?
Here is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

builder = tfds.builder('mnist')
builder.download_and_prepare()

(raw_train, raw_test) = builder.as_dataset(split=[tfds.Split.TRAIN, tfds.Split.TEST])

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=6, kernel_size=5, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, input_shape=(28, 28 ,1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=5, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
# model.add(Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(120, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(84, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10))

result = model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# model.summary()
train_images = []
train_labels = []
for i in raw_train:
    image = i["image"]
    # image = image.reshape(-1,28, 28, 1) 
    train_images.append(image)

    label = i["label"]
    train_labels.append(label)

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)
```

UPDATE :

I have tried advice convert list to numpy.array. I tried it but didn't able to wait for the result because it took only 1 core of CPU and use it on 100%. I spent 30 minutes but didn't receive the result yet. I believe there should be a different more right approach. I'm looking into batch and prefetch side but anyway I don't know how to get the result

the new code looks like this

```
import tensorflow as to
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np

builder = tfds.builder('mnist')
builder.download_and_prepare()

(raw_train, raw_test) = builder.as_dataset(split=[tfds.Split.TRAIN, tfds.Split.TEST])

raw_train = raw_train.batch(128).prefetch(128)
raw_test = raw_test.batch(128).prefetch(128)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=6, kernel_size=5, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, input_shape=(28, 28 ,1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=5, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
        # model.add(Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(120,activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(84,activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10))

result = model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                      metrics=['accuracy'])

train_images = []
train_labels = []
for i in raw_train:
   image = i["image"]
   train_images.append(image)

   label = i["label"]
   train_labels.append(label)

with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
   model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)
```

I still have error: 
    ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), for inputs ['dense_5'] but instead got the following list of 469 arrays: [

Comment: What about using `np.array(train_images)` when feeding to fit the model?

Comment: thanks alan.elkin for your advice, I've added these lines 

```
images = np.array(train_images)
labels = np.array(train_labels)
model.fit(images, labels, epochs=10)
```

but, in this case, i receive error  
> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (469, 1)

Comment: Could you please provide the model summary output? Also, what is the task you are addressing here? You have 10 outputs but a binary cross entropy loss

Answer (score 0):

it is not exactly answer ... because it solves my problem but brings another one) First of all I think it is not the best idea to transform a list of tensors into one 4D tensor because it performed using NumPy which uses one core of my CPU - I wasn't able to wait for the result of this operation. I figure out there is another approach which I like more and from my perspective, it looks better - it is using tf.dataset.map then batch then prefetch functions. I don't know how to use them yet, but I'm digging to this side.. and for now, I think it is more right and perspective way.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np


builder = tfds.builder('mnist')
builder.download_and_prepare()

(raw_train, raw_test) = builder.as_dataset(split=[tfds.Split.TRAIN, tfds.Split.TEST],shuffle_files=False)

def divide(record):
    image = record["image"]
    label = record["label"]
    return image,label

train_ds = raw_train.map(divide , num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE).batch(128).prefetch(128)
test_ds = raw_test.map(divide , num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE).batch(128).prefetch(128)
print(type(train_ds))

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=6, kernel_size=(5,5), activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, input_shape=(28, 28 ,1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5,5), activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(120, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(84, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10))

result = model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_ds))

print(image_batch.shape)
print(label_batch.shape)

with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
    model.fit(image_batch, label_batch, epochs=10)
```

This code also doesn't work but I think it is because the model expects 32x32 instead of 28x28 which I fed to the model. I'm still working - if you know how to fix the issue and how to manipulate batches please let me know. I appreciate your advices.

Answer (score 0):

It is not finished but I have next step. in order to make the prev code work, i added one_hot_y = tf.one_hot(label_batch, 10)

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np
from time import time

builder = tfds.builder('mnist')
builder.download_and_prepare()

(raw_train, raw_test) = builder.as_dataset(split=[tfds.Split.TRAIN, tfds.Split.TEST],shuffle_files=False)

def divide(record):
    image = record["image"]
    image = tf.image.resize_with_pad(image, 32,32)
    label = record["label"]
    return image,label

train_ds = raw_train.map(divide, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE).batch(128).prefetch(128)
test_ds = raw_test.map(divide , num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE).batch(128).prefetch(128)
print(type(train_ds))

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=6, kernel_size=(5,5), activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, input_shape=(32, 32 ,1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5,5), activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(120, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(84, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10))

result = model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])


image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_ds))

print(image_batch.shape)
print(label_batch.shape)

one_hot_y = tf.one_hot(label_batch, 10)
print(one_hot_y.shape)

with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
    model.fit(image_batch, one_hot_y, epochs=10)
```

The next step is to figure out which steps are right to move through the whole items in the dataset using batches.

Comment: Please do not post multiple answers for what it seems to be an ongoing investigation. Edit & update your previous answer instead. Also, no reason to include here commented -out parts of your code (edited out).